# Elegantly add text above certain bins on the histogram (optionally highlight them graphically, but use only black, white, grayscale for colors)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, confidence-interval

## Preface

I have a histogram for a vector with a vertical line of the actual value of the parameter, as in the figure below.

[image]

I also have a date frame of confidence intervals, which are constructed as follows:

from the actual value, I retreat left and right by (the width of the bar of the histogram) * k, where "k in N" until the probability is 1.
That is, the first interval has a left border with a real value — the width of the histogram column, and the right border with a plus, etc. as in the picture below.

[image]

## Problem

So how do I elegantly add all the probabilities according to their interval above the corresponding bars (taking into account the possible asymmetry of the histogram relative to the actual value) to the left and right of the actual value (ie for each pair of bars add the corresponding probability)?

Or how is it easier to build this histogram and find this date frame intervals?

## Not necessarily

How to graphically highlight data pairs of columns using only white, black, and shades of gray?

## CODE

Here is my code for plotting a histogram and finding intervals.

```
# find bin width for vector
find_bw <- function(vector)
{
  breaks <- hist(vector, plot = F)$breaks
  # ACHTUNG!!! HARD-CODE
  round(breaks[2] - breaks[1], 10)
}
find_bw <- cmpfun(find_bw)

# create hist for vector
create_hist <- function(vector, value, title, name_xlab)
{
  # check bin width
  breaks <- hist(vector, plot = F)$breaks
  bw <- find_bw(vector)
  
  # create hist with ggplot from standard hist
  ggplot(mapping = aes(vector)) +
    stat_bin(
      geom = 'bar',
      breaks = breaks,
      color = "black",
      fill = "white"
    ) +
    labs(title = title,
         x = name_xlab) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = value,
               linetype = "dashed",
               linewidth = 1.5)
  
}

# create conf ints for vector
create_conf_ints <- function(vector, value)
{
  n_breaks <- length(hist(vector, plot = F)$breaks) - 1
  bw <- find_bw(vector)
  
  future_map(1:ceiling(n_breaks / 2),
             function(n_half, bw, value)
             {
               half_int <- n_half * bw
               
               left <- value - half_int
               right <- value + half_int
               
               data.frame(
                 left = left,
                 right = right,
                 n_breaks = n_half * 2,
                 p = mean(vector >= left & vector <= right)
               )
             },
             bw, value) %>%
    bind_rows
}
```

## DATA

Similar to a normal distribution, the maximum vector length is 1000.

I tried to divide the segments into “right and left” and find the smallest distance between the interval boundaries and the column boundaries, but I didn't like this code, sorry, but it didn't save, and I don't want to reproduce that horror again.